# Hölder's inequality when $p=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What about Hölder's inequality for $p=1$ and $ q= \infty $ . I mean , does the following inequality hold?  For  $  \sup_n |a_n| < \infty$  and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert b_n \rvert < \infty  $ ,

$$   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_nb_n \rvert \leq \sup_n \lvert a_n \rvert
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert b_n \rvert .$$

If yes, how can one prove it?

Comment: Yes it holds, but it's meaningless when $\sup_n |a_n|=\infty$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = \infty$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM On the contrary, the inequality is trivially true in the cases you mention.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I edited to eliminate the trivial two cases. So, how can one prove this inequality?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen yes, "useless" would have more appropriate

Comment: Since $|a_n|$ is bounded by *constant*  $\sup\limits_k |a_k|$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$, so you first bouned it within $\sum$, then you take out the $\sup$ out of the $\sum$, and it's done.

Comment: @GNUSupporter You could make that an answer.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen LeGrandDODOM has made it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\sup_n |a_n|$ and note that for all $n\geq 1$, $|a_n b_n|\leq A|b_n|$.

Summing from $n=1$ to $n=N$ yields $\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n b_n|\leq A\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|\leq A\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|$

The sequence $(\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n b_n|)_N$ is increasing and bounded, thus convergent and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n b_n|\leq A\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|=\sup_n |a_n|\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|$$

Comment: very helpfull thank you!